# Air iOS/Android push notification remember when app launches

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, air

I have an app built for iOS and Android which has push notifications. Everything is working great however I was wondering if there is a way to store the data of the push notification in the app so that when users launch the app after receiving a notification I can show them the message again?

Basically I allow users to share information and/or chat amongst their friends. If they receive a notification when the app is in the background it comes through as a normal push message but when they launch the app I would like to direct them to the chat feature to see the message again.

I am storing the messages sent in a remote DB but seeing as they have already received the payload it doesn't make much sense for the app to call the remote DB to retrieve the same message.

I am using Distriqt's extensions in AS3 and Air 3.5.

Cheers

Comment: use SQLITE to store messages locally

Comment: Cool. So I can still access the apps db even though it is not running? What about global variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked Distriqt's support for the same thing a few weeks ago and they explained that there is no way to get the information of the push notification message while the app is closed so they suggested this :
- when the user opens the app, you call your server to check if they haven't missed anything, and get the data from there. If there has been a push, you display the push message as if it was received with the app in the foreground.

It's a bit tricky and not very satisfying but it works.. As long as the user follows the path.
If your user receives the push and chooses not to open your app, he will still get the push message in your app next time he opens it.

Comment: Bugger! So would it be best to say set a viewed flag in the DB, send the DB ID with the payload, then use something like foreground_notification and inside that method call the remote DB to update the viewed flag to true. Then when the app launches, call the remote DB for messages with view flag false, repackage and send again. Seems quite messy. Let me know if I am not understanding the suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Here is what I did. The push notifications were about news so it was quite simple.
The client sends the notification.
- A. The app is open the user receives it. (I store locally the id)
- B. The app is not opened, when he opens it, I check for any pushed data I could have missed on the db, get the data, see that it's not checked as received locally and then display it.

in the LocalData Object I just have an array with all the ids seen.

Not sure if that helps. Your project implies a lot more of all these interactions. :/

Comment: Hi, I'm one of the main developers at distriqt. We are currently working on a solution to this and hope to have something soon for APNS. If you follow us on G+ or twitter will announce it as soon as it's available. 
https://twitter.com/distriqt
https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/102477834526618173369/102477834526618173369/posts

Comment: @Antonine Thanks for that. What I ended up doing was storing a 'received' flag in the DB. With the extensions pnReceived set the flag to 1. When the app launches check for all unread items then simply set the 'is_sent' flag back to 0 and push the notification again. Probably not the best approach but it works and ensures delivery of the message the way it is meant to be delivered. Doing this also allowed me to notify the user what section of the app has notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble figuring this out too but I found a solution! Basically if a user launches an app (not running in the background) by way of a notification it comes through in the Invoke event, not the usual Notification event. So do this:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, invoked);

private function invoked(evt:InvokeEvent):void
{
    if (evt.reason == InvokeEventReason.NOTIFICATION)
    {
        var payload:Object = Object(evt.arguments[0]);
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

That's pretty much it. There's more detail in this blog post here: http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/05/29/push-notifications-support-in-ios/

Answer (score 0):

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, invoked);
```

doesn't work correctly for Android push notification. Android starts with InvokeEventReason.standard all the time, so we cant receive message. It works only for iOS.